# Make a lines orbiting around circle div

Tags: css, animation

i am trying to create animation that a few lines are rotating around circle div.

Something like this

http://prntscr.com/dxoe8o

this is my html & css

```css
.outCircle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  left: 270px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.duringTen {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.linear {
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.counter {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: inherit;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: inherit;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: inherit;
  -webkit-animation-name: inherit;
}
.rotate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: circle;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
}
.inner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
@keyframes circle {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outCircle">
  <div class="rotate linear infinite duringTen">
    <div class="counter">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My try is only with one line but i would like to create a few more lines like on the picture i posted above.
This is as far as i have come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```css
.outCircle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.marker {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.vert {
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.angle-1 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.angle-2 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: circle 3s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes circle {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outCircle">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="marker horiz"></div>
    <div class="marker vert"></div>
    <div class="marker angle-1"></div>
    <div class="marker angle-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, this is quick and dirty...with a little time it could be simplified, perhaps by using pseudo-elements for some of the markers.

In general though, a SVG might be better.